# Quantity of connections per data source in spring jpa

Tags: database, spring

In Spring Boot application, i have multiply data sources created for different databases. When looking on the number of connections opened to every database, it appeared that number differs for every database dataSource was created for. I wonder, how Spring determines how many connections should be opened for every data source configured? 
I would appreciate any help on this.

Comment: have you looked into database connection pools check out c3p0 or apache dbcb2. Both are great libraries for connection pools.

Comment: What dbs are you using?

Comment: I'm using mysql and jdbc connector. @locus2k Thank you for the hint. However c3p0 just gives some limitations but it doesn't explain why connections are different for different dbs